# How to move Google App Maker app to own server?

Tags: google-app-maker

How to export Google App Maker app to own server? I know it is possible to export app structure, but I cannot find tool to convert it to standalone app.

This files I can export from system:
- MANIFEST.json
- application.json
and folders with JSON files:
- models
- pages
- relations
- scripts (and JS files)

Comment: Does not seem to be possible. I have just even tried taking the html file and put it in a free standing Google Apps Script file and it does not render even in there.

Comment: It is using this script to complies JSON to HTML. httpss://github.com/google/closure-compiler

Comment: Google just announced that App Maker will be shut down on January 19, 2021. It will be great to have a way of exporting project to other system.

Comment: I think there are a lot of us that wish that was the case. Unfortunately it appears that will not be the case.